# How to prioritize in OR condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, between

I have a simple query where I want to search for a value in a column, and if no match is found then I want to discard that where condition and select any random value from that column.

I have tried to achieve this using `OR` condition, using case, but to no avail

```
select top 10 * 
from tblRFCWorkload 
where (f1 ='mbb' or f1 = f1)
```

In the above query I want the result table to have all rows with 'mbb', if 'mbb' is not found then give any value instead of mbb. But instead it returns only two rows with mbb even though there are 10 matching rows

```
select top 10 *
from tblRFCWorkload
where 1 = case when f1 = 'mbb' then 1 else 1 end
```

This query also returns the same result as the 1st query

If I change it to

```
select top 10 *
from tblRFCWorkload
where 1 = case when f1 = 'mbb' then 1 else 0 end
```

then it only rows having the mbb value.

Need similar thing with between clause... search for one range if no results found then search for second range... how do I do that???

Comment: Now I wish to do the same with between operator... if no values found with first range only then filter by second range.. how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select top 10 *
from tblRFCWorkload
order by (case when f1 = 'mbb' then 1 else 2 end);
```

This prioritizes the rows that you want, fetching the top 10 which will be `'mbb'`, if they are available.

Answer (score 0):

You want only the results where `f1 = 'mbb'` if there are any, otherwise nothing? In that case you need to be testing whether there are any matching rows. Something like this

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM tblRFCWorkload 
WHERE f1 = 'mbb'      --the match you need
OR NOT EXISTS         --or there are no matches
    (SELECT * FROM tblRFCWorkload WHERE f1 = 'mbb')
```